# How to get tr:nth-of-type(odd) for entire table not group (thead, tbody)?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS I set the zebra-striping background color for tables using tr:nth-of-type(odd). Of course, this is the first child of parent. Is there a way to specify this is the index for the table instead of the parent groups? For example, here is the outcome:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background: blue; }
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>Blue
    <tr>
    <tr>Blue
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>Blue
    <tr>
    <tr>Blue
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>Blue
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

What I would like:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background: blue; }
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>Blue
    <tr>
    <tr>Blue
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>Blue
    <tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>Blue
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Pictures for posterity:

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, you need to use JavaScript to achieve that. In jQuery: `$('table tr').filter(':odd')` http://jsbin.com/yuhug/1/edit

Comment: Do you have to use thead and tfoot?

Comment: p.s. I LOVE your username haha

Comment: Yes. I have to use thead and tbody for other reasons.

Comment: BTW, if you add the js as an answer I'll accept it. I ended up having to do `$("table").each(function(){
   $(this).find("tr:even").css('background', '#e1e9f0');
  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of how to do this using 100% CSS :/

BUT! Of course you don't have to use `thead/tfoot` as the only required element is `tbody` ;)

SO, this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dB6K/) is has the row coloring you want!

You could class the faux `thead/tfoot` rows in a class if you like :)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>faux thead blue</th></tr>
    <tr><th>faux thead not</th></tr>
    <tr><th>faux thead blue</th></tr>
    <tr><td>not</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Blue</td></tr>
    <tr><td>not</td></tr>
    <tr><th>faux tfoot blue</th></tr>
    <tr><th>faux tfoot not</th></tr>
    <tr><th>faux tfoot blue</th></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But in case you HAVE to use thead/tfoot, you could use the preceding, *er*, *cough* following *cough* jQuery/JS:

```
$("table").each(function(){ $(this).find("tr:even").css('background', '#e1e9f0'); });
```

Comment: I was thinking js was the only way but I wanted to see first if anyone could think of any CSS way. I have to use thead and tfoot for other things so I can't get rid of it.